# Provide a user with a symbolic temporary link to a file on a server

Tags: security, hyperlink, web, symlink

Is it possible to provide a user with a symbolic temporary link to a file on a server?

Example: I want to give my music album to a user. If he paid me, I generate on the fly a temporary symbolic link to an actual link on server side and send him. Is this a common practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is very much common practice.

These are similar to the URLs used for password reset, or password recovery.

Essentially a long random string, which is stored in your db, with an expiry of say 1hr, 1day or 1 week as is your policy.

In the db, the random string is mapped to the user, file, etc.

If the URL is accessed, the db is looked up, updated with access time, and the file transferred over. By storing the access time, and success status of transfer, you can even prevent it being downloaded multiple times with the same URL.

If you use AWS for your files, you would use url_for on the music album object, generate the url with an expiry time, and give it to the user - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method

Comment: But why am I often able on several MP3 streaming websites to generate direct download link by, for example, reverse engineering their flash MP3 player, or sometime, just their javascript and find the hashurl function. I'm just a beginner and I can do it, so why they don't all protect them with temporary URL? That's why I thought it was impossible.

Comment: @leye0 there's no reason it's 'impossible'. For the streaming mp3 sites it might be easier for them to give the raw url to the client instead of generating a hashed custom url for each play.

Comment: In fact, sometimes, they recreate the hash in the MP3 flash player directly. So they often use real links in the form of 'hard to find' hashes. What I wonder is if it's so difficult to use symbolic links for very big website. If their main source of cash is MP3, why not hiding direct access to mp3... Thanks for your infos about AWS. :)